# How to extract all substrings with regex pattern matching in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

**String:** `Lorem ipsum {{dolor}} sit {{amet}}, consectetur adipisicing {{elit}},`

I want to extract a list of all tags which are wrapped in {{ }} from above mentioned string and work on them i.e check db if they exist or not and than replace them as markdown link as follows.

```
[substring](/tag/:substring_id)
```

i can replace them with

```
String.replace(string, ~r/\{\{.+?\}\}/, "new substring")
```

but this doesn't help me because i can't work on substrings i.e check the db.

i didn't find any String.scan or String.find type of functions which returns substrings as a list. if you know how to do it than please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your effort and time :)

Comment: Is the string constant except for the portion in the {{}} part?  I ask because if it is constant otherwise you  could use pattern matching for this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.replace/4`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#replace/4) with a function as replacement:

```
db = %{"dolor" => 1, "elit" => 2}

string = "Lorem ipsum {{dolor}} sit {{amet}}, consectetur adipisicing {{elit}},"

Regex.replace(~r/{{(.+?)}}/, string, fn whole, tag ->
  if id = db[tag] do
    "[#{tag}](/tag/#{id})"
  else
    whole
  end
end) |> IO.puts
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum [dolor](/tag/1) sit {{amet}}, consectetur adipisicing [elit](/tag/2),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Regex.scan/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3) function if you simply want to extract the matched regex expression into a list of values.

```
Regex.scan(~r/\{\{.+?\}\}/, string)
#[["{{dolor}}"], ["{{amet}}"], ["{{elit}}"]]
```